# How do I pump up my quarterstaff's damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, weapons

Okay. So I have a medium quarterstaff for my level 10 monk5/black knight5/Low Templare5 character that's currently doing 4d6 points of damage. It's using Shillelagh(Continuous), lead blades (Continuous) for the special properties as well as Impact for the enchantment.  Right now, I only got 1000 gold left to use as well as getting one extra feat slot.

**Is there a way to improve the damage of the quarter staff through feats or extra enchantments?**

The feats my character has are:

- Nimble
- Low-Light Vision
- Prehensile Tail
- Diamond Armor (Su)
- Diamond Blade (Su)
- Weapon Finesse
- Leadership
- Necromantic Affinity
- Prestigious
- Power Attack
- Furious Focus
- Master Craftsman
- Craft Magic arms and armor
- Flurry of Blows
- Perfect Strike
- unarmed strike
- Way of the Weapon Master (Ex) Weapon Focus(staff)
- fast movement
- maneuver training
- still mind
- Ki Pool
- slow fall 20 ft
- High Jump
- purity of body
- deflect arrows
- Dodge
- Aura of evil
- detect good
- smite good 2/day
- touch of corruption
- unholy resistance
- Aura of cowardice
- Cruelty (Exhaustion)
- Knights’ Charge (Ex)
- Horseflayer (Su)
- Feindish boon
- Mount (Ex)
- Dread Banner (Ex)
- Hideous Immortality (Suffication)
- Most Agonizing of Corruption
- Crusader +2 (Ex)
- Flag of Convenience (Ex)
- Dirty Fighting (Ex)
- Sneak Attack (Ex) (1d6)
- -Path of Darkness(Su)

Comment: Some more information would help.  Like, we could suggest the obvious Weapon Specialization, if you're a fighter that is. Or doing two-weapon fighting with it to possibly get more attacks, or Power Attack if you're two-handing it...  I assume you know about some of these given the large set of abilities you already have - why are you not going for these?  And if you only have 1000 gold, how are you getting another feat? Have you leveled and have a free feat slot?

Comment: Lead blades and impact do not stack unless you play with a house-rule that allows it. In Pathfinder effects that treat a weapon as if it was bigger do not stack because both would look at the base size and increase that size by the number of steps given by the effect.

Comment: The FAQ for my above comment is here: http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t5u - I was too slow to edit it.

Comment: No really, we need more information to make a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use your open feat slot to get leadership. Although a lot of DM's ban it outright.

The [Good Hope](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/goodHope.html) Spell increases weapon damage by +2 as a morale bonus. This would be available to you if you get a bard Cohort

> ## Good Hope
>
> This spell instills powerful hope in the subjects. Each affected creature gains a +2 morale bonus on saving throws, attack rolls, ability checks, skill checks, and **weapon damage rolls**.

A bard Cohort would also be able to use [Inspire Courage](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/classes/bard.html#inspire-courage)

> ## Inspire Courage
>
> An affected ally receives a +1 morale bonus on saving throws against charm and fear effects and a **+1 competence bonus** on attack and **weapon damage rolls**. At 5th level, and every six bard levels thereafter, this bonus increases by +1, to a maximum of +4 at 17th level.

Furthermore, if you have a wizard or sorcerer in the party you could buy a wand of [Enlarge Person](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/enlargePerson.html#enlarge-person) for 750gp and have the wizard/sorcerer use it on you. By becoming bigger your damage dice increase by one step.